# Jquery not updating text in elements more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, input, getelementbyid

So I have a textfield that has onblur/onkeyup/onclick triggers. This works fine.

It takes the value and adds it in a `<b id="search_term"></b>`. This works, but only the first time visually. However, inspector shows it's being updated every time.

The element being updated is in a fixed position and I use the JQuery `$( "#search_results" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {});` to show the container element if the search input is not empty.

If I click the close button to trigger the `slideUp()` function, for a split second you can see the updated text in the element before the element disappears.

Has anyone come across this phenomenon? Searching has yielded nothing similar.

I've tried

```
$("#search_term").text(string);
$("#search_term").html(string);
document.getElementById("search_term").innerHTML=string;
```

None of them update with the actual variable.

I've also tested using JQuery to retrieve a value out of a textbox. If you change the value of the textbox after you've run the function once, the only possible way to get the updated value is via `$('#test_box').attr("value");`
`.text()` and `.html()` still show the very first value.

Is this a bug in JQuery or am I doing something wrong?

Been trying to solve for hours. Thanks for any advice.

**Edit:**
Narrowed it down to being an issue with `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`. If I remove them and only use `.show()`, the element updates normally.
Is there a way to force the element to re-render? Or should I find a replacement for slideDown/Up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being what I was doing inside of `slideDown()`.

I was doing:

```
$("#seach_container").slideDown("slow", function() {
    document.getElementById("body").style.position="fixed"; // to prevent bg scrolling
    document.getElementById("body").style.overflowY="scroll"; // to prevent doc jumping
    // Applying these two lines multiple times was giving me the issue of text not updating.
});
```

I ended up setting a boolean to make sure I only changed the position to fixed once. Fixed it right away.

So very specific situation, but maybe this solution will save someone else the 6 hours it cost me. hah

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for this is that you have bound an event to an element that has been removed / re-added and so the event is gone.

Changing the `text` in itself should be able to go on indefinitely, as per this example:

```
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="test">Go</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
   $('#example').text(Date.now); 
});
```

See it running by clicking the GO text as much as you like here: http://jsfiddle.net/5BXqg/

Comment: You're right, it does work there. I have narrowed it down to being an issue with slideDown() and slideUp(). If I remove them and only use .show(), the element updates normally. Any thoughts there?

Comment: No - that's odd because `slideUp` only affects `height` and `display` styles. It shouldn't affect your events. Can you stick a working problem example on http://jsfiddle.net ?